# Should the REST Services consumed by the Xamarin.Android app be PCL enabled

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am trying to consume JSON based REST services for developing a Xamarin.Android application. Now in this case the services are already developed and hosted and ready to be used. I am looking to consume them from the Xamarin.Android application.

We are also planning to develop Xamarin.iOS app and consume the same REST services.

Can anyone help me to know in this case whether the REST services should be PCL enabled.

Comment: You should create a Portable Class Library (PCL) project inside your app solution. This PCL project should connect to your REST services via HTTP or via a library (like REFIT or RestClient)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this from the PCL, and I recommend it. As often as possible you should move any code you can to the PCL. Anything not in the PCL means you have to code it twice, which means more likely to have bugs or discrepancies. Stuff that should be OS specific is View layout and utilizing OS specific libraries.